# Kill process by name in ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, process

How do I kill a process by name? I tried the following. (process name is php script.php)

> kill 'php script.php'

But this doesn't stop the process. How can I stop a process by name ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `killall php`. But note that it kills all PHP processes, not just those running script.php.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pkill`.

From man page:

> pgrep, pkill - look up or signal processes based on name and other

Example: `pkill <process_name>`

For more information :https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill

Answer (score 0):

you can use a combination of kill, ps, grep and awk commands to achieve it efficiently.

ps -aef : returns all the running processes

grep "php script.php" : returns only the matched processes

grep -v "grep" : ignores the grep process

awk '{print $2}' : returns only the process ID

kill : Kills the process using process ID

To kill "php script.php" :

```
kill $(ps -aef | grep "php script.php" | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}')
```

pkill is also a good option to choose